# How to call FreeMarker directive from ftl template directly?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, freemarker

**Short Question**:
Is it possible to call FreeMarker directive `FormatDirective.java` that implements `TemplateDirectiveModel` directly from my ftl like this:

```
<#assign formattedPhoneNumber = "com.myapp.utils.FormatDirective"?new(phoneNumber)>
```

**Detailed Question**:
It's Spring MVC web app that has its views written with FreeMarker, there are no Java configs at all and I have only `FreeMarkerConfigurer` and `FreeMarkerViewResolver` beans properly defined and configured in `root-context.xml`.

I want to avoid Java configurations (like adding template to model or shared variables).
And what is the proper way -in general- to get Java directives working ? I don't seem to find thorough tutorial or example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect your frequently used directives and functions into something like `my-commons.ftl`:

```
<#assign format = "com.myapp.utils.FormatDirective"?new()>
...
```

then in your templates:

```
<#import "my-commons.ftl" as my>
...
<@my.format value=phoneNumber />
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Does that require adding the directive instance to View model or define it as shared variable from xml configs ? Or should work they way you described without any other configs ?

Comment: It should work without any configuration, because the imported template itself points to the class to instantiate.

Comment: Thank you, that was actually useful.
However I implemented the solution in a different way due to some constraints but inspired by your input.